# What evidence is there for Nietzsche's division of people into higher and lower types?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism, humanism

What evidence is there that there are two types of people, specifically an elite higher type?

Did Nietzsche have authentic reasons to suppose that?

Comment: Maybe a reading of some introduction to Nietzsche can help...

Comment: If this is a question about Nietzsche, I'd advise you to rephrase the question accordingly. It reads at present as if you are asking on your own behalf for evidence of there being an elite. Reword the question so that it reads as a question internal to Nietzsche's philosophy.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas It seems to me anon has done what you asked by writing "Did Nietsche have authentic reasons to suppose that?" The "that" being whether there are two types of people.